# Medata preparing error with pip install sentence-transformers

Tags: python, metadata, sentence-transformers

When I try to install sentence-transformers, i get this:

```
Collecting sentence-transformers
  Using cached sentence_transformers-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting transformers<5.0.0,>=4.32.0 (from sentence-transformers)
  File was already downloaded c:\users\administrateur.win-87mr2krtigi\desktop\python\llama-index\transformers-4.37.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tqdm (from sentence-transformers)
  File was already downloaded c:\users\administrateur.win-87mr2krtigi\desktop\python\llama-index\tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting torch>=1.11.0 (from sentence-transformers)
  File was already downloaded c:\users\administrateur.win-87mr2krtigi\desktop\python\llama-index\torch-2.2.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl
Collecting numpy (from sentence-transformers)
  File was already downloaded c:\users\administrateur.win-87mr2krtigi\desktop\python\llama-index\numpy-1.26.3-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl
Collecting scikit-learn (from sentence-transformers)
  Using cached scikit_learn-1.4.0-1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting scipy (from sentence-transformers)
  Using cached scipy-1.12.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
Collecting nltk (from sentence-transformers)
  File was already downloaded c:\users\administrateur.win-87mr2krtigi\desktop\python\llama-index\nltk-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting sentencepiece (from sentence-transformers)
  Using cached sentencepiece-0.1.99.tar.gz (2.6 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Administrateur.WIN-87MR2KRTIGI\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-download-eylr7dz3\sentencepiece_c76fcda444de4973979ae3fb5a19c9b8\setup.py", line 126, in <module>
          subprocess.check_call([
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 408, in check_call
          retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

My packages:

```
aiohttp                   3.9.3

aiosignal                 1.3.1

annotated-types           0.6.0

anyio                     4.2.0

attrs                     23.2.0

build                     1.0.3

CacheControl              0.13.1

certify                   2023.11.17

charset-normalizer        3.3.2

cleo                      2.1.0

click                     8.1.7

Colorama                  0.4.6

crashtest                 0.4.1

dataclasses-json          0.6.3

Deprecated                1.2.14

dirtyjson                 1.0.8

diskcache                 5.6.3

distlib                   0.3.8

distro                    1.9.0

dulwich                   0.21.7

fastjsonschema            2.19.1

filelock                  3.13.1

frozenlist                1.4.1

fsspec                    2023.12.2

greenlet                  3.0.3

h11                       0.14.0

httpcore                  1.0.2

httpx                     0.26.0

huggingface-hub           0.20.3

idna                      3.6

installer                 0.7.0

jaraco.classes            3.3.0

Jinja2                    3.1.3

joblib                    1.3.2

jsonschema                4.21.1

jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1

keyring                   24.3.0

llama_cpp_python          0.2.38

llama-index               0.9.40

MarkupSafe                2.1.4

marshmallow               3.20.2

more-itertools            10.2.0

mpmath                    1.3.0

msgpack                   1.0.7

multidict                 6.0.4

mypy-extensions           1.0.0

nest-asyncio              1.6.0

networkx                  3.2.1

nltk                      3.8.1

numpy                     1.26.3

openai                    1.10.0

packaging                 23.2

pandas                    2.2.0

pathspec                  0.12.1

pexpect                   4.9.0

pillow                    10.2.0

pip                       23.3.2

pkginfo                   1.9.6

platformdirs              3.11.0

poetry                    1.7.1

poetry-core               1.8.1

poetry-plugin-export      1.6.0

ptyprocess                0.7.0

pydantic                  2.6.0

pydantic_core             2.16.1

pyproject_hooks           1.0.0

pyproject-metadata        0.7.1

pyproject-toml            0.0.10

python-dateutil           2.8.2

pytz                      2023.4

pywin32-ctypes            0.2.2

PyYAML                    6.0.1

rapidfuzz                 3.6.1

referencing               0.33.0

regex                     2023.12.25

requests                  2.31.0

requests-toolbelt         1.0.0

rpds-py                   0.17.1

safetensors               0.4.2

scikit_build_core         0.8.0

setuptools                69.0.3

shellingham               1.5.4

six                       1.16.0

sniffio                   1.3.0

SQLAlchemy                2.0.25

sympy                     1.12

tenacity                  8.2.3

tiktoken                  0.5.2

tokenizers                0.15.1

toml                      0.10.2

tomlkit                   0.12.3

torch                     2.2.0

torchvision               0.17.0

tqdm                      4.66.1

transformers              4.37.2

trove-classifiers         2024.1.8

typing_extensions         4.9.0

typing-inspect            0.9.0

tzdata                    2023.4

urllib3                   2.2.0

virtualenv                20.25.0

wheel                     0.42.0

wrapt                     1.16.0

yarl                      1.9.4
```

Can anyone help me?

I have installed or updated:

```
llama_cpp_python, multidict, numpy, pip, pyproject-toml, 
scikit_build_core, setuptools, torch, torchvision, transformers, wheel.
```

Comment: did you run `pip install -U sentence-transformers` or `python -m pip install -U sentence-transformers`?

Comment: pip install sentence-transformers because it is my first install, python -m could help me?

Comment: I tried both... same error.

Comment: Did you use a virtual environment? Have you tried installing in a virtual environment?

Comment: i do not have ; directly on windows server 2016. I'm not used to working in a virtual environment with python.

Answer (score 0):

i found it: the dependency sentencepiece is not compatible with pyhon 3.12.